# A dense cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{T}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be the circle group. I want to know if there exists a cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{T}^n$ which is dense. For $n=1$ this is easy. Since we know that $\{m+n\sqrt{2}:m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ we can look at the exponential map $t\mapsto \exp(2\pi t)$ which must have a dense image. How to solve for $n>1$? Clearly, it is enough to show that there exists real numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb R$ such that $\{(m_1+ka_1,\dots,m_n+ka_n):m_j\in\mathbb z,k\in\mathbb Z,1\leq j\leq n\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: @hdighfan Why not an official answer?

Comment: It’s official now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct so far, and [Kronecker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem) finishes it off.